# How can i get numFound with Solr streaming

Tags: solr, streaming

I am using Solr streaming in my project which was using Solr without streaming. I stuck in the place where i need a numFound(total no. of records). How it is possible with streaming?

Comment: A streaming expression (if that's what you're talking about) is usually meant to evaluate everything in the stream as it appears from the sources and are processed by each step (i.e. there might be no knowledge of the actual number of rows after the whole set of expressions have been evaluated). I'm not sure if talking about numFound makes sense in that context, except to look at the number of rows left after the last step in the chain?

Comment: Right now our angular client uses this numFound to determine the number of pages required to show the total result. On every page number click a new call to api comes which correct offset values. Now we are migrating those APIs with akka streams and using slick solr support which uses solr streaming. The problem now is , if i dont pass the numFound how angular client know how many pages it needs to create, or do we need to change angular client implementation to be compatible with new APIS.